# How to sort firebase array by number

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I have the following [firebase schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quUXx.png) and using this code `$firebaseArray(talksRef.orderByChild('time').limitToLast(100))` in order to sort but somehow it doesn't sort correctly at all. And I suspect that firebase stores the number as string so sorting returned incorrectly. So my question is how to store actual number into firebase data and sort them out accurately.

Thanks